# Add more space (padding) into NVD3 line chart max and min

Tags: nvd3.js, ng2-nvd3

Let's take the example below:
[krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart)

[image]

I want to add more space (kind of padding) between the min/max of the line chart and the x-axis/top.

There is this an [option called `yDomain`](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#lineChart):

> Defines the whole Y scale's domain. **Using this will disable calculating the domain based on the data**.

The bold part means if I set the min to be -100, if my chart goes below that level, I won't see it anymore. Or, if the min of my chart is actually -50, then -100 would be too much.

So basically I want the min and the max of the Y-Axis to be 10% of the (respectively) min and max of the chart.

Comment: Did you try setting marginTop?

Comment: There's no such thing as marginTop in the nvd3 options..

Comment: .margin({top: 100})

Comment: No, margin is not what I want. Margin adds space outside the chart. I want to add more spaces between the min and the x-axis and as well as the max and the top of the chart

Comment: In fact, I want an equivalent of [padData](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#lineChart), but vertically.

Comment: I just posted the  answer. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. It was just math. :/

We need to get the y-min/y-max first:

```
const min = Math.min(...data.map(d => d.y));
const max = Math.max(...data.map(d => d.y));
```

And then (if we want 15% margins):

```
{
    ...
    yDomain: [min - (max - min) * 0.15, max + (max - min) * 0.15]
    ...
}
```